# How Do I Setup Python Game Dev Server on Digital Ocean?

Tags: python, digital-ocean, game-development

I looked through the community and a google search but couldn't find quite what I am looking for.

I am trying to setup a game development and eventually a production server on DO for a multiplayer text-game I am making.

I'm not concerned about size/speed yet as I'll just scale that as necessary. I simply want people to visit the webpage that has the game on it and play the game. I can do all of this locally simply by running the python file and visiting the html page. What I can't quite figure out is how I would set this up on a production machine.

The game is a series of python files (with one main game file) and is accessed via html/js with an underlying python websocket.

I've created a Django web server before (with gunicorn/nginx), so I can get some html to load, but I'm stuck on how exactly I also get the game to run.

Is there a better/easier way than setting this up with Django? Not looking for alternatives (e.g. Flask), just different approaches with less setup requirements.

What's the best way to set this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Digital Ocean has a pretty thorough guide [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) that details the steps needed to install and setup a Django based stack on one of their virtual private servers.

Once you have installed and set everything up, you should probably configure the init system of your VPS to automatically start when the server boots or reboots. Many modern Linux distros use the Systemd init and service manager system. Systemd will not only automatically start your Django based application as a service when the server boots, but it can check if the service has stopped and restart if it stopped running.

Digital Ocean has a good tutorial about using the various init systems to make a program start automatically and restart if it crash. The tutorial can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples). It might also be helpful to take a look at the [website](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) for the Systemd project.

Hopefully this gives you a better idea of how to run a Django based site in production.

Comment: I did mention that I've done that before. I don't have a problem setting up Django. I even used that tutorial. My problem lies in the running of the actual game on the server. For example, do I initialize the game from within the web server settings somehow or something else entirely?

Comment: It looks like systemd might be what I'm looking for. I'll look at that.

Comment: You will initialize the games via Systemd using what is know as a service file. In Systemd service files are used to describe how a particular service should be run on a host. It defines things like what to execute, whether it should start on boot, what user ID it should run as, and if it should be restarted if it crashes, among other things